# Outlook rule to run a script which filters body source

Tags: vba, outlook

I saw that we could use the MailItem.HTMLBody element but I did not understand how to do it.

It is simply a matter of detecting the term "email <o: p>" in the source of the received email. Once transmitted, I want to move the email to a folder already created, or to be created by the script.

```vb
Sub filter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim source As String
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim MailDest As Outlook.Folder
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    source = Item.HTMLBody
    If InStr(source, "email<o:p>") > 0 Then
        Set MailDest = ns.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("test")
        Item.Move MailDest
    End If
```

If I remove "Item", do I have to use ThisOutlookSession module?

And then, what are the precise steps to get it triggered?

When I create a rule that detects the object I don't have "run macro" in the list.

I need to create a rule "If email from hello@me.com" that triggers this VBA but I can't find that in Outlook rules manager.

Comment: Your sub has a parameter: `Item As Outlook.Mailitem`. This means that it can only be called by another sub, not from a button, because it will need to enter a value for `Item`. How do you want this value to be populated?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I need to create a rule "If email from hello@me.com" that triggers this vba but I can't find that in outlook rules manager... Moreover, if I remove Item, do I have to use ThisOutlookSession object ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine

- Activate Run a script in regedit
- Activate Developer menu and Macro
- Use the script below
- Create the rule

```
Public Sub filter(ByRef MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim source As String
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim MailDest As Outlook.Folder
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    source = MItem.HTMLBody
    If InStr(source, "email<o:p>") > 0 Then
        MItem.Move myInbox.Folders("MyFolder")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not technically be an answer but putting it here anyway in case it's of use to someone.
I don't know if it's close enough, but I've quickly adapted a code I use that filters through an entire folder for emails matching certain conditions (in this case I've reset the conditions to 'email from hello@me.com and contains email<o:p>' and moves them to a separate folder. It might be just what you need, it might not. What it *will* do is trigger from a button (pro tip, can be assigned a button in your home tab or custom tab of your choice) on the active folder in outlook.
Give it a try;

```
Sub filter()
'Variables:
Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem, MyFolder As Outlook.Folder, MailDest As Outlook.Folder
'Set fixed Variables:
With Application
    Set MyFolder = .ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder 'This means the sub will work on whatever the active folder is at the minute.
    Set MailDest = .GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("test") 'I like doing things all in one go if poss.
End With

With MyFolder
    For a = .Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If TypeOf .Items(a) Is MailItem Then
            If InStr(.Items(a).HTMLBody, "email<o:p>") > 0 _
            And .Items(a).SenderEmailAddress Like "hello@me.com" Then
                .Items(a).Move MailDest
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With 'MyFolder

End Sub
```